# Как сделать исключение для определенного IP для redirect в apache?

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, https

Можно ли как нибудь сделать исключение, что бы редирект с domain.com на https://domain.com не работал, если на сервер заходишь с определенного айпи?

Comment: хорошо, сделаю несколько вопросов

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
ReWriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.11\.11\.11$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

где `11.11.11.11` — *ip* сервера.

```
ProxyPass / 11.11.11.11.com/dir1/dir2
```